# Parsing text string using delimeter

Tags: java, text, maps

I have a text file:

Structure:

```
key1: xxx
key2: 
key3: 
key4: 
key5:value5
key6: This is an example text file to add data 
       this is an example text file 
       this is an example text file
       this is an example text file
key7:
```

I have tried to parse it, but finding it difficult to split using delimeter      ':' and to add into maps so that i can access the values based on keys. I have tried below code.The problem is key6 where there is a paragraph and the code tries to split using delimeter after every new line. Any help to deal with this    issue is much appreciated.

```
try{
    Map<Object, Object> map = new Properties();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader
    (new FileReader(textString));      
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String fields[] = line.split(":");
            map.put(fields[0], fields[1]);
        }
        br.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    LOGGER.debug("Exception", e);
}
```

Comment: sort your description out.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? You can use `Properties.load()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)

Comment: Do you have any chance to restructure your file? If you would be able to use a quoted line break like "\n" instead of having them, you could treat each line a a record.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing the split after reading each line. Why not parse the whole text, then perform the split. Like this

```
try{
    Map<Object, Object> map = new Properties();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader
    (new FileReader(textString));      
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
        while (br.readLine() != null) {
            text.append(br.readLine());         
        }
        br.close();


     String fields[] = text.toString().split(":");
        for(int i=0; i < fields.length-1; i++){
            map.put(fields[0], fields[1]);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
    LOGGER.debug("Exception", e);
}
```

**NOTE**

If any of the values contain a colon it will break your data. With this solution or what you are currently doing. Ideally, if you could, would be to use the [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) class part of the java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it as a key value and store it into map. Then do not use : use = . For next line value you can use \ symbol it will pick up the value from next line.

**Properties File:**

```
key1= xxx
key2= 
key3= 
key4= 
key5=value5
key6= This is an example text file to add data \
       this is an example text file \
       this is an example text file \
       this is an example text file
key7=
```

**How to fetch value:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
         Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("prop.properties"));

        for (final Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            map.put( (String)entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        for (Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Entry type = (Entry) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(type.getKey());
            System.out.println(type.getValue());

        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
key1
xxx
key2

key5
value5
key6
This is an example text file to add data this is an example text file this is an example text file this is an example text file
key3

key4

key7
```